# Send multiple attachment in mail php

Tags: php, email

```
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);

// header
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

// message & attachment
$nmessage = "--".$uid."\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$path = 'https://childlearning.in/dev/uploads/events/attachment/';
$nmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
foreach($pics as $pic)
{

    $filename = $pic;
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $content = file_get_contents( $file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$attachment .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$attachment .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$attachment .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$attachment .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$attachment .= "--".$uid."--";


}
$allattach = $attachment;
$nmessage .= $allattach;
//print_r($nmessage);
//die();

if (mail($mailto, $subject, $nmessage, $header)) {
    echo "Sucess"; // Or do something here
} else {
  echo "Fail";
}
```

This code work fine for me, but it only send single attachment. I want to send multiple attachment, each time this send attachment in mail only the attachment in the first array list. What I missing , I did't get . Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$pics` is definitely a single array. Do a `print_r($pic);` below `foreach()` and show us what that gives.

Comment: 2 attachment is showing

Answer (score 0):

Pics is declared properly ?

```
$pics= scandir('picsorwhatever/');
```

Comment: well if its the first row every time it mean something wrong with the loop try echoing attachement inside the loop and nmessage after and post the result

Comment: loop works fine , its show all the attachment when echoing